# Web application to organize and serve a library of PDF files

Tags: database, pdf, web-applications

I have a large library of PDF ebooks, and I'm looking for a web app to host on my site to organize and sort a database of the files, as well as have the ability to annotate them by adding data like publisher, year published, keywords, authors, etc. I have a great hosting provider ([WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/?affiliate=pigimal)) with access to all sorts of frameworks, like Drupal, Django, Rails, Node, etc., as well as MySQL and Postgres servers, so the language and back-end aren't that important, although .NET is out.

I've searched all over and just can't seem to find anything that fits the bill, although it seems like someone ought to have open-sourced this before. I'm not interested in services like Mendeley (http://www.mendeley.com) or [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com), but rather something I can host myself, both to overcome file size limits and privacy issues, but also so I can check out the source and modify it if needed.

Comment: this is off-topic, but you should check out [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to need a document management system.

Check out [OpenKM](http://www.openkm.com/en/) or [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/products/document-management)